# How to get git diff colorization also within vim when committing?

Tags: macos, git, vim, git-diff

When I view `git diff` I see all those nice colors for removed and added lines. Yet when I `git commit -av` to both read and reject or accept the commit, all I have is ugly one-colored text.

My `.gitconfig` contains:

```
[color]
        diff = auto
        status = auto
        branch = auto
        ui = true [core]
        excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
        editor = vim
```

I know that it works because I used to have it set up on a Ubuntu machine. I am on OSX though having installed git with homebrew.

How do I get those nice colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to setup `~/.vimrc` and add:

```
syntax on
```